# How to open up external packages/libraries in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

While working with a peer who used pycharm, I noticed he was able to open up the packages of external libraries in our app. In other words, he could dig in to the source code of that library/package. When I try to CMD + click external libraries in VS Code, this isn't possible; I can only do it with files/modules that are within my own code base. Can I enable this somewhere in the settings?

There is a `Go To Definition`, however, this is "empty" when I end up clicking on an external package.

Comment: I would try the context menu. Isn't there something like Goto Definition? You haven't tagged the language you are using. I presume Python?

Comment: Did you installed plugins for python? At least I installed the python plugin from MSFT and one day it prompted me to install python linting(if I remember correctly it ended up running a pip install in vscode terminal) and now I can drill into library code by hitting CMD + click. I am on Mac

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you have the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) installed (as pointed out by @congbaoguier) and at least the Microsoft language server turned on.

Comment: yeah i have that installed...no dice

Comment: Then either there's a deeper problem with the paths on your system and the language server can't find the files or there's a bug as I can't go into Python's stdlib without issue. If you can come up with a reproducing scenario please open a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server.