# Debugging external module code in vscode/ jupyter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, jupyter-notebook

I wish to inspect the code inside a (pip installed) module that I've imported (called transformers if it is relevant). So right now what I am doing is putting `breakpoint()` where relevant in the site_package location and calling the module inside `test.py`.

```py
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer, EncoderDecoderModel
```

However, Ideally I wish to set and remove breakpoints on the fly as I inspect the code, as I could normally do with a python module I wrote. Wondering if there is something similar for external libraries.

### Alternate Solution

I would equally be happy if I could write `breakpoint()` where I need it to be on the fly. I used to do this with Jupyter with my own modules by adding the following two lines:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

However, this did not work for an external library when I added in new breakpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `"justMyCode": false,` in the launch.json file as the default value of it is true.

You can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode) for more details.

Comment: this works OK for regular Python files, but did not hel wiht Jupyter. Perhaps there are some additional parameters needed in `launch.json`. I tested with jupyter running in WSL.

Answer (score 2):

Use an IDE such as PyCharm or Visual Studio Code.

I use Jetbrains CLion that allows me to view external libraries code by right clicking -> Go To -> Declaration or usage.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483321/how-to-open-up-external-packages-libraries-in-vs-code).

To do your breakpoint() function, you will have to modify the external library code.

As mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075397/python-how-to-edit-an-installed-package), you should never modify an external library code. Alternatively, with an IDE you will be able to put breakpoints by clicking the line where you want to put a breakpoint.

But if you still want to edit the code, you should install the module with the [-e option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-e).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).